# Facebook fanpage app liking/login in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-like

More than looking at a exact solution. I'm trying to figure out the whole process and how it works regarding best practices. I have an app (Car Listing) and I would like to register the user for him to be able to post car listing for sale.

The whole idea is that the user must like the fanpage in order to see/browser the content.

I'm wondering; Do I have to create the User model when the likes the fanpage or when he tries to access the car posting page (cars/new) or does the whole process happens through facebook OAUTH?

I'm a fairly experienced web developer but I'm kind of lost when it comes to registration/liking through facebook. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank You

Comment: You won’t know anything about the user just because they liked your page, so creating a user object on your side at this point already would be pointless. You only get access to any user details after they connect to your app. And how that’s done, is explained very detailed in the docs.

Comment: Can you please point me in the right direction, because the docs talk about OAUTH and facebook-connect for third-party applications but I'm not sure whenever this is the right practice for fan-page tab apps?

Comment: Facebook uses OAuth for connecting users to apps, so if you want to know _anything_ about the user browsing your app, that’s your way to go. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/login/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you looking for an elegant solution I was able to hit one in the devise wiki.

Here explains step by step on setting up OmniAuth and how the whole process works from a Rails standpoint.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview